# publishJms nifi jms server in weblogic

Tags: jms, apache-nifi

sorry I'm newbie in nifi , I need to send messages from nifi to jmsserver in weblogic , I have followed this tutorial with the same example:

https://blogs.oracle.com/soaproactive/jms-step-2-using-the-queuesendjava-sample-program-to-send-a-message-to-a-jms-queue

but not sure what is the vallue of the property in "MQ ConnectionFactory Implementation" when I configure the "JMSConnectionFactoryProvider" , Can someone help me please?

Comment: Tried `weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory`?

Comment: If you follow that example, for Weblogic, your JNDI factory should be "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory" - this is the class that knows how to do the rest.
The name 'jms/TestConnectionFactory' will be loaded from your WebLogic server and if configured, return a ConnectFactory containing all your specific properties.

Did you store and configure a jms/TestConnectionFactory in your WebLogic server ?